# column split to another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is the input

```
fld_Detail
Saved dollar rate, gold volume as: 42.61, 1663.40
312000000000083: Saved as GENT'S RING, , 18K, 11.20, 0.00
312000000000083: Saved as GENT'S RING, , 18K, 11.20, 0.00
312000000000104: Saved as NECKLACE W/ CONT. PENDANT GOLD, , 14K, 8.90, 0.00
312000000000064: 350
312000000000080: 340
312000000000082: 340
```

How can I change or split this set of records in order to achieve this kind of output

```
fld_DetailNumbers
312000000000083
312000000000104
312000000000064
312000000000080
312000000000082
```

In short I want to retrieve the distinct Numbers on the left of '**:**' based on the first records

I do not know how to split a whole row and retrieve its distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
select substring(fld_Detail, 1, charindex(':', fld_Detail)-1 )
where isnumeric(substring(fld_detail,1,1)) = 1
```

it's not very efficient, but then your data is not very 3rd normal form.

Comment: Thank you sir but i want to retrieve the numbers only, the first record contains text in the left of colon i want to disregard it how can i do it?thank you!

Comment: try what I just added

Comment: thank you sir it work like magic. im sorry if it's not in 3rd normal form im not the maker of the table and im just tapping in its data again thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some string manipulations:

```
select left(fld_detail, charindex(':', fld_detail) - 1) as valueToLeftOfColon
```

If you want this as a number, convert it:

```
select cast(left(fld_detail, charindex(':', fld_detail) - 1) as decimal(18, 0))
```

EDIT:

To fetch only numbers, you can do something like:

```
select (case when fld_detail like '%:%' and fld_detail not like '%[^0-9]%:'
             then cast(left(fld_detail, charindex(':', fld_detail) - 1) as decimal(18, 0))
        end)
. . .
where fld_detail like '%:%' and fld_detail not like '%[^0-9]%:';
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir but how can i remove the String the first record contains

`**Saved dollar rate, gold volume as**`

because i only need the numbers thank you so much for your great help.

Comment: in short sir i want to retrieve the numbers only, the first record contains text in the left of colon i want to disregard it, i want to disregard any records that contains text in the left of the colon how can i do it?thank you!

Comment: Thank you sir for your time i receive this kind of error
**Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**

Comment: @DanzaiVer . . . You have to be very careful when casting strings to integers in SQL Server.  In particular, the correct approach is to use `case`, which is the only part of the language guaranteed to do the test before attempting the conversion.